different starting point (in Survival Analysis)
We are conducting a study where patients are regularly tested for cancer recurrence. Check-ups are scheduled every four months (T0, T4, T8, T12, T16, T20).
My question is that these patients have different enrollment times. The first patient started in September, and the other one started in November. Can we still use the discrete-time model with fixed (the same) intervals even though the patients’ starting points are different? Can we say the data below is structured correctly to represent our findings?
ID     TIME   EVENT   GENDER    
1      T0        0      M       
1      T4        0      M        
1      T8        0      M        
1      T12       1      M       
2      T0        0      F         
2      T4        1      F         
3      T0        0      M     
3      T4        0      M       
3      T8        1      M       
4      T0        0      F     
4      T4        1      F 


This seems fine to me. Basically, your time variable is defined relative to the starting point of each patient. As long as you are clear about this in your methods, I don't have a problem with it.
EDIT: EdM makes the excellent point that it may be useful to also add the actual date of study as a predictor.

(+1) this happens in continuous-time survival models when participants enroll over the course of a study. The OP might consider adding the actual date of study entry as a predictor in the model, to allow for potential changes in baseline outcomes over calendar time.

@EdM, Thank you for the comment. I am not sure whether I fully understood your point. Does it mean that in a discrete time model using GLM (event ~ time, link = …), we can have different starting time points? Am I right?

@marco yes, there can be different calendar-time starting points in discrete-time models just as there can be in continuous-time survival models. My suggestion is that you might want to use the calendar time itself as an additional predictor. For example, sometimes there are changes in clinical care over calendar time that might affect survival in addition to the factors that you are modeling explicitly. Including the actual calendar time of study entry as a predictor can help with that.
